# Generating prediction using a back-propagation neural network model on R returns same values for all observation

Tags: r, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to generate prediction using a trained backpropagation neural network using the neuralnet package on a new data set. I used the 'compute' function but end up with the same value for all observations. What did I do wrong?

```
# the data
Var1 <- runif(50, 0, 100)
sqrt.data <- data.frame(Var1, Sqrt=sqrt(Var1))

# training the model
backnet = neuralnet(Sqrt~Var1, sqrt.data, hidden=2, err.fct="sse", linear.output=FALSE, algorithm="backprop", learningrate=0.01)

print (backnet)

Call: neuralnet(formula = Sqrt ~ Var1, data = sqrt.data, hidden = 2,     learningrate = 0.01, algorithm = "backprop", err.fct = "sse",     linear.output = FALSE)

1 repetition was calculated.

        Error Reached Threshold Steps
1 883.0038185    0.009998448226  5001

valnet = compute(backnet, (1:10)^2)

summary (valnet$net.result)

      V1           
Min.   :0.9998572  
1st Qu.:0.9999620  
Median :0.9999626  
Mean   :0.9999505  
3rd Qu.:0.9999626  
Max.   :0.9999626  

print (valnet$net.result)

         [,1]
[1,] 0.9998572272
[2,] 0.9999477241
[3,] 0.9999617930
[4,] 0.9999625684
[5,] 0.9999625831
[6,] 0.9999625831
[7,] 0.9999625831
[8,] 0.9999625831
[9,] 0.9999625831
[10,] 0.9999625831
```

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible dataset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that will allow people to get the same result as you, so that they can figure out what went wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [neuralnet prediction returns the same values for all predictions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572091/neuralnet-prediction-returns-the-same-values-for-all-predictions)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the following to work:

```
library(neuralnet)

# the data
Var1 <- runif(50, 0, 100)
sqrt.data <- data.frame(Var1, Sqrt=sqrt(Var1))

# training the model
backnet = neuralnet(Sqrt~Var1, sqrt.data, hidden=10, learningrate=0.01)

print (backnet)


Var2<-c(1:10)^2

valnet = compute(backnet, Var2)

print (valnet$net.result)
```

Returns:

```
     [,1]
[1,] 0.9341689395
[2,] 1.9992711472
[3,] 3.0012823496
[4,] 3.9968226732
[5,] 5.0038316976
[6,] 5.9992936957
[7,] 6.9991576925
[8,] 7.9996871591
[9,] 9.0000849977
[10,] 9.9891334545
```

According to the [neuralnet reference manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/neuralnet.pdf), the default training algo for the package is backpropogation:

> neuralnet is used to train neural networks using backpropagation, resilient backpropagation (RPROP) with (Riedmiller, 1994) or without weight backtracking (Riedmiller and Braun, 1993) or the modified globally convergent version (GRPROP) by Anastasiadis et al. (2005). The function allows flexible settings through custom-choice of error and activation function. Furthermore the calculation of generalized weights (Intrator O. and Intrator N., 1993) is implemented.

Comment: Please Correct if i wrong as mention in the document the Default Algorithm is `algorithm = "rprop+"` 
as Mention that `rprop+-- resilient backpropagation
with and without weight backtracking`